# Opendaylight netconf get-config returns ClassCastException on opendaylight custom feature

Tags: classcastexception, opendaylight

After I set the Yang node through NETCONF in a feature project of opendaylight,  I got the following error when I read this node. The data feels like it has been set, but there is this error when reading it. What is the possible problem? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="13">
  <rpc-error>
    <error-type>application</error-type>
    <error-tag>operation-failed</error-tag>
    <error-severity>error</error-severity>
    <error-message>Unexpected error</error-message>
    <error-info>
      <ERROR>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.data.impl.schema.builder.impl.ImmutableMapNodeBuilder$ImmutableMapNode cannot be cast to org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.data.api.schema.ContainerNode</ERROR>
    </error-info>
  </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>
```

Answer (score 0):

does "set the node" mean that you are mounting a netconf device? when you do
that, do you see any errors in karaf.log? You may see extra info, as well, in
karaf.log when you read the node. Not quite enough information in your question
for me to help much more. Oh, you could search opendaylight's jira for other
reported problems with [ClassCastException](https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/NETCONF-486?jql=text%20~%20%22ClassCastException%22)